# Google play store free vs paid apps

Tags: android, google-play-console

I am publishing an app on google play store that all purchases are done in the app and you don't have to pay to doanload the app(In app purchases?). Which category should I select? Paid or Free.

I have tried paid but google is asking me for the price of my app.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: Check @CommonsWare 's reply. Basically, choose free and configure your app to have in-app purchases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can publish your application for free. You can add in-app purchases.

> Best practices:
>
> Make your app available as a free download with limited features or
> full features for a limited time. Then use an in-app purchase to
> unlock the full, unlimited app.
>
> Offer additional features or content items through in-app purchases,
> such as new levels, special playing pieces, or other features in
> games.
>
> Use subscriptions where your app provides regularly updated or
> time-based content.

Also, Refer to this [Link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334373?hl=en) for a better understanding.